VHS child 90's animated movie about a leopard that goes to NY
When I was a child, I used to watch this movie I think is called something like 'Bolo' but I'm not sure. All I know about the movie is:

The main character is a feline, a leopard I guess  
In the beginning of the movie, he has a leopard girlfriend  
Hunters want to capture him. I don't remember if they succeed and the feline finds himself into a cage in the airplane, all I know is that he goes to NY City and there's a cage with him. When people saw him, they start to take pictures  
Somehow, he goes to a judgement of something.   
In the end, he returns to the jungle. 

Can anyone help me remember what movie is it? I want to watch it again 

When were you a child? Was the movie animated or live action?

in 90's. And was animated. Sorry, I'll put these information in the post.

I'd suggest a more descriptive title for the post as well.

is this title better?

Sounds like you're after The Bollo Caper from 1985.

Bollo, a leopard brought to New York to be made into a fur coat, manages to escape to Washington to try to get Congress to declare him an endangered species.

It was part of ABC's Weekend Specials and was based on the book by  Pulitzer winner Art Buchwald. Here are the first few minutes, which you've described well:




It's been years I'm trying to find this movie! Thank you very much!
